Azure SQL Server to on-premise (local) server database data-tier import error
I'm getting this error message whenever I import the .BACPAC data tier file that I exported from Azure SQL Server:

Could not import package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [database_name_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [database_name_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider:


Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "foreign_key_id". The conflict occurred in database "database_name", table "[dbo].[Table_name]", column 'Id'.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script:
PRINT N'Checking constraint: foreign_key_id [dbo].[Table_log]';
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_log] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [foreign_key_id];
(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

I've already checked and implemented the solutions provided in the following thread:

SQL72012 Error, this
Similar thread, and lastly this thread about
SQL72014 & SQL72045 Error

But I have no luck...

The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint “foreign_key_id”. The conflict occurred in database “database_name”, table “[dbo].[Table_name]”, column ‘Id’.

Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script: PRINT N’Checking constraint: foreign_key_id [dbo].[Table_log]’;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Table_log] WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT [foreign_key_id];

(Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)

According to  this the above error will get at the moment that the process has inserted all the rows in all tables and needs to enable the constrains/indexes. Points that a foreign key doesn’t exist in the related table.
To resolve the above error, follow below instructions:

Ensure either that no write activity is occurring during the export, or that you are exporting from a transactionally consistent copy of your database.

Ensure your SQL server is updated version.

Use latest version of SSMS, select import Data-tier Application in SSMS as shown below



For more information you can refer to the below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-copy?view=azuresql

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export?view=azuresql



In the instruction one, I can't guarantee a no-write activity in the database since the database that I was exporting is in production, however I'm exporting instances of the database in different times, I would be lucky if I can time a no-write activity.
